# Android instant run gradle error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-run

Sometimes when I use instant-run I get this error (mainly after layout.xml changes):

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':wear:transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForDevDebug'.
>
>   > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

Now my project needs a rebuild otherwise wont run and continues on giving me the same error.
But if instead of rebuilding it again I use the cmd with `./gradlew :wear:assembleDevDebug` the `:wear:transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForDevDebug` builds just fine and I'm able to run it again, though instant-run was lost.

So it fails when I try instant-run but it doesn't when cmd is used? Why is this happening?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Opened an issue in google code [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225574)

**EDIT 2:**
To reproduce this error in the cmd I had to change my layout.xml, like commenting a view, and then run `:wear:transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForDevDebug`.
The output:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':wear:transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForDevDebug'.
>
>   > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
> - Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>     ':wear:transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForDevDebug'.
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
>         at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
>         at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:239)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:212)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:205)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
>     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>         at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:147)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.shrinker.AbstractShrinker.waitForAllTasks(AbstractShrinker.java:347)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.shrinker.IncrementalShrinker.waitForAllTasks(IncrementalShrinker.java:275)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.shrinker.IncrementalShrinker.processInputs(IncrementalShrinker.java:241)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.shrinker.IncrementalShrinker.incrementalRun(IncrementalShrinker.java:96)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.NewShrinkerTransform.incrementalRun(NewShrinkerTransform.java:220)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.NewShrinkerTransform.transform(NewShrinkerTransform.java:119)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:178)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:174)
>         at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:173)
>         at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
>         ... 60 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>         at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>         at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.shrinker.IncrementalShrinker.processChangedClassFile(IncrementalShrinker.java:262)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.shrinker.IncrementalShrinker.access$000(IncrementalShrinker.java:47)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.shrinker.IncrementalShrinker$1.call(IncrementalShrinker.java:229)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.shrinker.IncrementalShrinker$1.call(IncrementalShrinker.java:216)
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 11.114 secs

Comment: for instant-run you need latest update of IDE, do you have it?

Comment: This is an Instant-Run bug in gradle 2.2.1 and AS 2.2.1, it happens to me too in random occasions. I still didn't found what change trigger this error...

Comment: @GaneshPokale yup AndroidStudio latests version, gradle also.

Comment: @MatPag this is such a bummer :/

Comment: @GuilhE yeah a bit annoying... Sometimes to get rid of it i need to close AS, delete the builds folder and restart AS

Comment: provide complete error and I think while  building it Error showing two times... update complete error message in question

Comment: I have deactivated instant run a while ago. For my taste it is still to unstable to be helpful.

Comment: @Henry me too, i don't have time to be a beta tester while working. I'm already using canary builds to help them improve AS reporting issues, i'm letting someone else help them improve instant run

Comment: @MatPag use the terminal and type ./gradlew :your_module:assembleDevDebug and after 20sec your up for running it again. It's faster than deleting build folders, etc..

Comment: @GuilhE thanks for the tip, i will try it if i will decide to re-enable instant run. Moreover i will build with   --stacktrace option and report the stacktrace in the android issues site

Comment: @MatPag ok ;) I've created an issue in google code, I've updated the post with the link. Thanks!

Comment: @GuilhE i think you should provide the full stracktrace to help them track the bug down

Comment: @MatPag ./gradlew :wear:assembleDevDebug --stacktrace like this?

Comment: @GuilhE no, you need to reproduce the bug using the offending assemble task. so it should be ./gradlew :wear:transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForDevDebug --stacktrace

Comment: @MatPag ok got it, will update both threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Android Studio 2.3 Canary 2](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio23canary2isnowavailable) is now available and it fixes this issue.